# How do I fix these labels at the end of line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am using the `ggrepel` package to add labels to the end of lines in ggplot. I am having an issue where the labels are overlapping and adding more labels than needed. I adjusted my `max.overlap` value a few times and was still getting overlaps. My 2022 line has no label on it. Attached an image of what was going on, and here is the code to generate the line. Do I need to add some y-axis nudge?

```
        output$creditPlot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(temp_df_long_credit_hours, aes(week, value, group = school_year, alpha = school_year)) +
        geom_line(lwd = 1.5,
                  show.legend = F) +
        geom_label_repel(aes(label = school_year), 
                         nudge_x = 4, 
                         na.rm = T, 
                         max.overlaps = 0,
                         stat = "unique",
                         show.legend = F,
                         force_pull = 10) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
    })
```

Dataframe used.

```
> dput(temp_df_long_credit_hours)
structure(list(week = c(-22, -22, -22, -22, -22, -21, -21, -21, 
-21, -21, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -19, -19, -19, -19, -19, -18, 
-18, -18, -18, -18, -17, -17, -17, -17, -17, -16, -16, -16, -16, 
-16, -15, -15, -15, -15, -15, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -13, -13, 
-13, -13, -13, -12, -12, -12, -12, -12, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, 
-10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
-8, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, 
-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), school_year = c("fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022", "fall_2018", "fall_2019", "fall_2020", 
"fall_2021", "fall_2022"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20761, 
18661.5, NA, NA, 10408.5, 56914, 49744.5, NA, 12039, 28930, 72070, 
62730, NA, 34960.5, 38809, 85278, 77023.5, NA, 46043, 47951, 
94803.5, 87161.5, 57634.5, 55161, 55711.5, 104565.5, 96156.5, 
66395, 62856.5, 61944.5, 113641, 103396, 76650.5, 69399, 67723.5, 
120581, 109970.5, 84893.5, 75854, 72565, 126255, 114543.5, 90434, 
81376, 75630, 131825, 119571, 95729.5, 85729.5, 79555, 136776.5, 
124173, 99772, 90196, 83577, 141738, 128459.5, 103475, 94700.5, 
87207, 147072, 133202.5, 108800, 98973.5, 91474, 152369, 138274.5, 
114452, 103632.5, 95704, 156527, 141785, 118685, 107489.5, 100413, 
162992, 147955.5, 124000.5, 111988.5, 107615, 170244, 154728, 
131260.5, 118594.5, 114076.5, 179047, 161710.5, 138620.5, 125615, 
120784, 188901, 168262.5, 147012, 133236, 129033, 200011, 177967.5, 
156769, 142968, 137916.5, 210551.5, 188592, 167904, 152467, 147424, 
221325, 197919, 180528, 162947, 158055, 223855.5, 199881.5, 183164, 
165206.5, 160699.5, 220775, 197768.5, 180640, 163221.5, 158929, 
220600, 198025, 180133, 163479, NA, 221621, 199232, 180923, 164650, 
NA, 222392, 200337, 182174, 165379, NA, 223202, 200842, 182492, 
166214, NA, 224024.5, 201569, 182758, 166424.5, NA, 224416, 202112, 
183081, 166685.5, NA, 224966.5, 202713.5, 183616, 167111.5, NA, 
225698.5, 203292, 184464, 167943.5, NA, 226119.5, 203663, 184718, 
168058, NA, 227276.5, 206149.5, 186401, 169126.5, NA, 227276.5, 
206149.5, 186401, 169126.5, 164678.706656292, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-185L))
```

[image: Example of line and label output]

Comment: Could you please include  the dataframe: use `dput(temp_df_long_credit_hours)` to make the question reproducible.

Comment: Updated post to include data. Thanks for that r command Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here maybe one option by creating a separate helper dataframe for the labels. A bit of tinkering around with the `geom_label` arguments will allow fine tuning of the labels. Editing `scale_x_continuous` `expand` argument allows adjustment of the margin to the plot to give the labels a bit more space.

The reason you are not getting a label for 2022 seems to be related to `NA` values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

labs <- 
  temp_df_long_credit_hours |> 
  na.omit() |> 
  group_by(school_year) |> 
  filter(week == max(week))|>
  mutate(vjust = case_when(school_year == "fall_2022" ~ 0.9,
                           TRUE ~0.5))


ggplot(temp_df_long_credit_hours, aes(week, value, group = school_year, alpha = school_year)) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(data = labs, aes(label = school_year, x = week, y = value),
            hjust = -0.1, 
            vjust = labs$vjust,
            show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.2)))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If I add more data to the frame will the 2022 label move with the new line endpoint? I think this answers my question as I have a few similar plots and this solution worked for those. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, the labeller dataframe will use the maximum value for `week` to position the label.